# XCode - Vertical TableView Carousel Style Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, tableview

I currently have a table view populated with a series of posts. What I am trying to achieve is to manipulate the table view scroll so that there is always one table view cell centred in the table view. I'd also like this to have some form of scroll snap, similar to a vertical carousel in which the centred / focused cell has a maximum alpha and original size, and the cells visible above and below are smaller and have a lower alpha. I have attempted using scroll target offset but with no luck. I am mainly struggling with the mathematics of the function.

The image below demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Demonstration Image]

What I am looking for at the very least is a push in the right direction in regards to how I can manipulate the table view scroll to have this type of carousel function.

EDIT: Is it possible to achieve this with Paging in the Table View?

Comment: Carousel is usually implemented as a UICollectionView, so just switch to that instead of table view and you’re all set.